# Member variables vs out parameters in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Which one is better? Declaring the member variable in the class or returning out parameters of methods?Performance aspect which one is better one.

```
class A{ 
    //Declaring member variable
    private string name;
    private int age; 

    private method Display()
    { 
        Passing(); 
        Console.Write("{0}-{1}",name,age); 
    }

    private void Passing() 
    { 
        name = "Hello World"; 
        age = 21; 
    }
}
```

Or

```
class A{
    //out parameter implementation 
    private method Display()
    { 
        string name= string.Empty; 
        int age = 0; 

        Passing(out name,out age); 

        Console.Write("{0}-{1}",name,age); 
    }

    private void Passing(out string name,out int age) 
    { 
        name = "Hello World"; 
        age = 21; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to answer in the abstract, neither of your code examples seems attractive though. What's wrong with just returning the string?

Comment: multiple out parameters possible

Comment: class A{
    //Declaring member variable
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private method Display()
    {
    Passing();
    Console.Write("{0}-{1}",name,age);    
    }
    private void Passing()
    {
     name = "Hello World";
     age = 21;
    }
    }

Or 
    class A{
   //out parameter implementation
    private method Display()
    {
    string name= string.Empty;
     int age = 0;
    Passing(out name,out age);
    Console.Write("{0}-{1}",name,age);
    }
    private void Passing(out string name,out int age)
    {
    name = "Hello World";
    age = 21;
    }
    }

Comment: Edit your question to include this code.  It does not belong in a comment.

Comment: I can't able to edit my code.

Comment: Now I updated my code too. Please provide me proper guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, the former.  Using out parameters is generally not a great idea.  Don't get me wrong, out params have their uses, but in the case of setting state like in this case don't use them.  They are good for things like TryParse where you return a bool indicating whether the parsing was successful or not and then return the result of the parse in an out param.

Comment: out can't be used on declared variables

Comment: While I agree on using the first solution, I disagree on the statement that `out` parameters are generally not a great idea. There are many scenarios where `out` parameters are great.

Comment: I was getting to that - I wanted to write my answer in stages

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Out *must* be used on declared variables, as in C# every variable needs to be declared.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar strait from MSDN "The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is similar to the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before being passed. To use an out parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword."

Comment: @ColeJohnson: And how is this is related to your statement saying `out` can't be used on declared variables?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I said uninitialized, not undeclared

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No, you did not. Look at the second comment to this answer (which happens to be your very own comment), where you say *out can't be used on declared variables*, which is wrong in more than one sense: a) every variable in C# must be declared and b) even if you meant "initialized", you would still be wrong, as you *may* pass an initialized variable as an `out` parameter - it just doesn't do anything as the initial value is discarded.

Comment: @ThorstenDitter then check my comment on my answer. It's this gay thing. Anyways then what would be the point of out if it's the same as ref?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11525/discussion-between-cole-johnson-and-thorsten-dittmar)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: `out` is not the same as `ref`. Passing a variable to a `ref` parameter allows you to use the variable's original value, but also allows you to change the variable's value. Passing a variable to an `out` parameter *discards* the original value upon calling the function - you can not use it, but you *must* assign a new value to the `out` variable. This even gets more fun when passing objects as `ref` parameters. You can not only change properties of the passed object instance, but you can make the variable "point" to a new object.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar well. Learn something new every day then. I'll delete my answer

Answer (score 7):

No one of them. I would go for:

```
class A
{
    private void Display()
    {
        string name = Passing();
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
    private string Passing()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

If you want to return more than one thing I would encapsulate that in an object like such:

```
class A
{
    private void Display()
    {
        var person= Passing();
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name + ": " + person.Age);
    }
    private Person Passing()
    {
        return new Person() {Name = "John Doe", Age = 99 };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it will worth to add that We can use Tuple or dynamic object in .net 4.0 onwards to return multiple values combined in an object.

Comment: @Romil, of course we can, but I think you should avoid them if you can. They are great in some cases, but if you can get things strongly type and get your code checked during compile time I would go for that.

Comment: @TomasJansson: Using `Tuple<>` is strongly typed, too, isn't it?

Comment: @Thomas, you are right, but sometimes if already defined classes/Struct is not there then we need to use.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, you are right. `Tuple<>` is strongly type, in that case it falls down to use an object if you can, that will most likely communicate the purpose of the code better.

Answer (score 3):

Ummm, neither. Why not have a return value?

```
class A
{
    private void Display()
    {
        string name = GetString();
        Console.Write(name);
    }

    private string GetString()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

OK now that we know what you are trying to achieve, if the method is purely internal to the class it then depends on the scope of the values you are returning. If they are logically contained in the class, go for member variables. If they are scoped only for internal use in a method, go for out parameters or a custom type as the return value (a `Tuple<>` can be used here).

You could even use an anonymous type, but as Jon Skeet eludes to, it is a little hacky:

https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Comment: There is multiple parameters possible. So return not possible.
private void Passing(out string name,out int age). so multiple out parameters possible.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question.

Comment: Still not getting proper answer from any one. what is drawback of using multiple out parameters

Comment: @sarooptrivedi You have plenty of working answers. I don't know of any drawbacks other than aesthetics when it comes to having too many out parameters.

Comment: my method is return bool and multiple out parameters now which is better way to implement. declaring multiple member variables or write multiple out parameters

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be :

```
class A
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Passing passing = new Passing("Hello World");
        Console.WriteLine(passing);
     }
}

class Passing
{
    public Passing(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}", Name);
    }
}
```